# How to reduce the total file size of two standalone Node.js apps?

Tags: node.js

Assume we have 2 .js files, and we want to use [`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) to package the 2 Node.js packages into 2 standalone executable files. The problem is that the total file size of the 2 executable files would be unnecessarily big, because both of them (I believe) have the interpreter Node.js embedded inside. Is there a way to extract the common part out and have it become a shared library shared by the 2 standalone executable files? If it's possible, we'll only need to distribute 3 files (2 executable + 1 library) to our clients. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat `pkg` purpose?

Comment: indeed, if I'm understanding and remembering everything correctly, that sort of defeats the purpose of pkg. It seems to me what you're really looking for is a way to run "node program.js" with a known version of node, and wrap that in an exe so that the client doesn't have to use the command line. If that is the case let me know as I have an idea of how you could do that

Comment: for personal use just putting a batch script in with your .js files that runs "node program.js" and then creating a shortcut to that batch script should suffice, but it seems to me like you want to be able to quickly distribute it to computers that don't already have node installed

Comment: @MilesZew Yes, you're right. My clients don't need to be aware of what Node.js is. I'm writing a C++ app and want it to run some useful Node.js apps as its sub-processes, but the problem is that Node.js has its ecosystem, and it isn't a good idea to ask our clients install Node.js in their computers. In short, it'd be great if the Node.js apps can be installed just like ordinary binary executable files, and even better if their common part (i.e. Node.js itself) can be put in a shared library. Thanks.

Comment: @Cody actually, the fact that this is happening within a C++ app makes everything much more easy - I'll have to do some quick research as I'm not super familiar with C++ but I'll post an answer soon

Comment: @Cody are you fine including minified .js files with your program? I don't see why you wouldn't be, except in the case that you want things to be a bit more obfuscated, but I figured I should make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is a bit clunky/hacky for a few reasons, so it might not be the best long terms solution, however I believe it should work fine for what you need.

Based on what you've told me in the comments, this shouldn't be too difficult of a thing to do. First, download the node binaries for the OS's that you need (https://nodejs.org/download/release/). If you're worried about weird conflicts with users that have node installed on their machine you could rename to program to `nodeP.exe` (P for portable) or something like that, but as far as I know it shouldn't be a problem.

Next, since space is a concern, you should minify your .js files. Then, when you want to run the files, just get your parent program to execute `nodeP.exe program.js`. I believe in C++ you can just run `system('nodeP.exe program.js')`.

That being said, I have never used this solution myself, nor am I very experienced in this particular area, so you should definitely test this a bit before actually using it (for example, I'm not sure what happens if an error occurs in `program.js`).

If any problems crop up feel free to ask

Comment: What about the dependencies of `program.js`? In Perl's world, command-line tool `pp` is able to bundle all modules of a Perl script, combining them into a single one script, so that the combined one can be run by interpreter without client installing Perl modules. That is, only the combined script and interpreter are required. Is there a similar tool in Node.js' world? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the noise. Just found that `webpack` is able to bundle a JavaScript and all its dependencies.